# Retrieve array from postgres

Tags: php, arrays, postgresql, pdo

Very basic question but couldn´t find a solution.

In a table with some values I try to store in 1 column a array (int[]) and retrieve it. The storing and searching works fine but if I select it I get it as string in php.

Table week

```
col id (int) = 1
col days (int[]) = {1,1,1,1,1,0,0}
```

PHP

```
$query = SELECT id, days, manyother FROM week //array_to_json(days) does the same result
$pdo->setAttribute( PDO::ATTR_CASE, PDO::CASE_NATURAL );
$result = $pdo->query($query);

$test = $result->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
echo json_encode($test)
```

Returns:

```
id: 1
days: "[1,1,1,1,1,0,0]"
manyother: ""
```

I´m sure I miss just something with json_encode/decode
Edit: its not affected by json_encode, I debuged it and before it returns the value like '[1,1,1,1,1,0,0]'.

Edit 2: Found a solution which works but increases the loading time 15* times :D So the question is still open but I have a workaround for the moment.

```
foreach($test as $key => $value){
        $test[$key]['days'] = json_decode($value['days']);
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

when selecting array, you can hack the way array is displayed:

```
t=# select json_build_array(array[1,2,3,4])->0;
 ?column?
-----------
 [1,2,3,4]
(1 row)
```

It should be easily evaluated by php then with eval. Or even `json_agg` on whole data set and then eval:

```
t=# select json_agg(s162) from s162;
json_agg
[{"i":0,"a":[1,2,3,4]},
 {"i":1,"a":[1,4]}]
(1 row)
Time: 0.281 ms
```

Comment: workdays:"[1,1,1,1,1,0,0]" still returns as string in response. I used Select json_build_array(days)->0 FROM week

Comment: sure. you still have to eval the string to get array

Comment: yes my question is how to do this. At the moment I get an string from postgress but I want an array.

Comment: probably by looping between rows and `$day=eval($test[$i]["day"]);`

Comment: Sry that I have t ask but could you explain it a little bit more clearly, I dont get it. The way you wrote it, it would return the whole table as array, but I just need the one column values converted.

Comment: json_agg will turn json the whole table, yes. json_build_array will turn one column a json array. both values looks TEXT for PDO - so you have to `eval()` them to become array and so on. so youhave to loop throough the resul casting data type for json_build_array, or just cast the whole set to json and then use it instead of php data array

Comment: Ah I think I understood, thank you. I done nearly the same as workaround (see edit). This works but increases the loading time extremly. Converting the whole set would mean I cant really work with the data in php before returning it. I probably go back to mongo, it seems postgress has here a lack of a database function, which I need quite often.